# Out-File when copying items and removing them

Tags: powershell

I got a script to take backup and to remove files in generations (group). I need to add some logging of which files it copies and also which ones it deletes. In all my previous scrips, I been using `Out-File`, but in this case for the copy I can't get it to work.

If I add it to the `Copy-Item` part it creates the file but it simply wont write any input. What I am missing?

```
#$a = Get-Date
#$a.ToUniversalTime()

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -File $localpath -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)})) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup\$file.$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)"
}
$Groups = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\qlikview Storage\privatedata\backup" |
          Group-Object -Property Basename |
          Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2}
foreach ($g in $Groups) {
    $g.Group |
        sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
        select -Skip 2 |
        foreach {del $_.FullName -Force}
}
```

The #a is for later to add timestamps the logging to see how long it takes.
Am I thinking wrong assuming `Out-File` is the way to go?

Comment: If you want to create backups, would it not be smarter to use an *actual* backup software? Windows 10 has the "Backup and Restore" tool from Windows 7 built in (it's in the Control Panel), which works very well.

Comment: No, not for this. This works perfect, just the logging of the copy thats the problem.

Comment: add a _separate line of code_ that adds to your logging file. stop trying to cram everything into one line of code ... [*grin*]

Comment: `Remove-Item` doesn't produce output unless an error occurs or you add the parameter `-Verbose`. Verbose output can be written to a file via the `4>>` or `*>>` redirection operators (assuming you have a recent enough PowerShell version). A simpler approach would be `Start-Transcript`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-Verbose` switch to your `Copy-Item` and `Remove-Item` commands. This will dump the copied/removed files to the [verbose stream](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/).

Afterwards you can redirect the verbose stream to the output stream (`4>&1`) and log it the a file.

Example :

```
Copy-Item... -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-file log.txt
```

Additional info can be found in [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6).

Comment: You' welcome. Please mark the answer as correct one. Thx.